# How to remove errors UnsupportedOperationException and Possible memory leak

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web-applications

I have been searching a lot but have not found a perfect one which can help me to solve this problem.
I have web services and am generating the stub using JAX-WS.
To access the methods of web services I have wriiten a class in which all the methods are static like

```
public static String getLocation()
{
 //call to the web service
}
```

I am specifying static because I want to confirm this is not the root cause of my problem.
Now when I am checking the logs in the Tomcat directory the catilina log shows some thins like this...This error is occured when I Startup or shutdown the tomcat server

```
Mar 18, 2010 11:13:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: stop: Stopping web application at '/testWeb'
Mar 18, 2010 11:13:07 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader    clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a thread named [leakingThread]  but  has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Another error I am seeing is

```
SEVERE: Unable to determine string representation of value of type      [com.sun.xml.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl]
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at com.sun.xml.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.entrySet (XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:2134)
at java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearThreadLocalMap(WebappClassLoader.java:2433)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferencesThreadLocals(WebappClassLoader.java:2349)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferences(WebappClassLoader.java:1921)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.stop(WebappClassLoader.java:1833)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stop(WebappLoader.java:740)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4920)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:936)
```

Please can any one help  me to clear these errors.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "and possible memory leak" is in context to text in my question.

Comment: OK - my bad. Following the lead of @MarkoTopolnik - leave it as one question.

Comment: Thanks Marko...can you please help in solving the exception..I am searching a lot..but....:(

Answer (score 1):

My diagnossis: you have a `Map` implementation in a thread local, and this map doesn't support the operation `entrySet`, which is triggered by `Map#toString`. To be precise, your exception is thrown from [this line of code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/xml/internal/stream/writers/XMLStreamWriterImpl.java/#2157) in `com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl`.

Tomcat's code that clears the thread local is quite unfortunately written to *unconditionally* call `toString` on objects just to be able to log them *if the debug level is on*.

If you can't get rid of using a thread-local for this, you may have quite some trouble working around this problem.

Your thread leak, by the way, is very probably the result of failed cleanup due to the above error.

Comment: Marko . I think you are on the right note. I am using Map to set the session variables...like "private Map session = null;" and its showing me warning to add arguments. will adding argument sole my problem?

Comment: That's not a thread-local. Are you using the `ThreadLocal` object? It may also be used internally by your WS framework, it's hard to tell. The compiler is complaining about type arguments to the generic type `Map`. Completely unrelated.

Comment: It's JAX-WS-related. `Map` class is `com.sun.xml.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl`.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you Marko...but how can I fix it...in my action class I am using java.util.Map